# mysql database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, doctrine, database-schema

I'm designing database schema for sport centers data.

Each `center` has many `sports` (football, tennis, table tennis...).
Each `center` has many `courts`.
Each `court` belongs to one `sport`.

I need to expose following data:
 - Get all sports that you can play int single center.
 - Get centers court by sport
 - Get all centers that have `sport` court. (Example get centers with `tennis` courts).

This is database schema that I have:

[image]

I wanted escape triangle relationship.

I'm wondering is this schema fine, or there is better way to do it?

Comment: "I wanted escape triangle relationship." - Why?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't have good explanation for it. I'm taught that it is a bad practice, but I have never question it. Could you kindly explain it, is that what people usually do?

Comment: But yet you have accepted an answer with a "triangle relationship".

Comment: I don't have center and sport in relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good and data will be stored in a fine way.

You can also make a chain in order to reduce the realationships, for example
you can make Center ->(1:n)Sports->(1:1) Court . In this way you can avoid to have a court which does not have a sport (because in the full conection schema this problem can appear)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "over-normalization".

I would have 2 tables.  One would have details on each center (address, etc).  The other would have:

```
center_id
sport_id
court
```

If the operating hours are for the whole center, then this belongs in the first table.  If the different courts have different opening hours, then it belongs in the second table.

`sport_id` could link to a third table that includes `name`, `slug`, `icon`.

Comment: Good idea. Each sport have following properties `id`, `name`, `slug`, `icon`. If I want to change icon for football I would need to update each row that have football sport?

Comment: @jsepar00 - I incorporated your Comment into my Answer.